# Getting column sums from a 2D dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c, dynamic, 2d

I have a dynamically allocated 2D array of lines that look like this:

```
2152,1,MAIN,AAST,2337,1,26873,LEC  - Lecture,5,5,0,0,0,Ronnie W Liggett,liggett@uta.edu,COBA,348,9:00 AM,9:50 AM,Y,N,Y,N,Y,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,AAST,4391,1,26881,IND  - Independent Study,1,5,4,0,0,Schnavia S Hatcher,shatcher@uta.edu,,,,,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,AAST,3339,1,29501,LEC  - Lecture,5,5,0,0,0,Krystal K Beamon,kbeamon@uta.edu,UH,104,11:00 AM,12:20 PM,N,Y,N,Y,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,ACCT,3309,6,27298,LEC  - Lecture,59,59,0,0,0,Terra C Mcghee,tcbrown@uta.edu,COBA,256,9:00 AM,11:50 AM,N,N,N,N,Y,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
```

All 1000 lines are bubble-sorted alphabetically by their subjects (which is the fourth column, AAST and ACCT in the above example). I need to print the total enrollment for each subject, which is 9th column (5, 1, 5, 59 in this example). The code I have is below:

```
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
            total = 0;
            strcpy(currentLine, addresses[i]);
            currentSubject = getSubject(currentLine);
            for(i;i<count;i++)
            {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                    strcpy(nextLine, addresses[i]);
                    nextSubject = getSubject(nextLine);
                    if(strcmp(currentSubject, nextSubject) == 0)
                    {
                            strcpy(nextLine, addresses[i]);
                            enrollment = getEnrollment(nextLine);
                            total += enrollment;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            printf("%s          %d\n", currentSubject, total);                              
                            break;
                    }
            }



    }
```

where:

- addresses is the 2D array that contains all 1000 lines
- getSubject() extracts the fourth column using strtok()
- getEnrollment() extracts the enrollment column using strtok()
- count equals the number of lines in the file, which is 999 (the first line is a header line which is disregarded(

I keep using strcpy() to avoid corruption of the original string due to strok(). However, this logic doesn't seem to work, because my totals are displayed as:

```
AAST          11
ACCT          193
ADVT          12
```

The relevant lines (I removed all the useless information so it's easier to read) are:

```
AAST,5
AAST,1
AAST,5
ACCT,59
ACCT,26
ACCT,34
ACCT,37
ACCT,18
ACCT,59
ACCT,19
ADVT,136
ADVT,12
```

It looks like for ACCT, the second to last value (59) didn't get added, as well as for ADVT, the second to last value (136) also didn't get added. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: don't use `strtok`.  It is counterintuitive and error prone for `getSubject()` and friends to modify the string argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same index `i` for the nested loops. You should not increment it in the outer loop, and you should move the `printf` out of the inner loop to avoid missing the last entries.

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < count;) {
    total = 0;
    strcpy(currentLine, addresses[i]);
    currentSubject = getSubject(currentLine);
    for (; i < count; i++) {
        strcpy(nextLine, addresses[i]);
        nextSubject = getSubject(nextLine);
        if (strcmp(currentSubject, nextSubject) != 0)
            break;
        strcpy(nextLine, addresses[i]);
        total += getEnrollment(nextLine);
    }
    printf("%s          %d\n", currentSubject, total);                              
}
```